# Slick carousel width issue

Tags: slick.js, react-slick

On the desktop, I cannot seem to get the width to work on my carousel, it shows a little of the next one.

I have tried using javascript to get the width of the list but that breaks the float. Even if I put a simple image inside I have the same problem..

I am using react-slick module...dont know if that helps...

http://34.205.143.7/community/

Here are the settings:

```
  const settings = {
      dots: true,
      lazyLoad: false,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 750,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      initialSlide: 0,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      centerMode: true,
      responsive: '',
      arrows: false,
      accessibility: true,
      onInit : () => {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sliderContainer').width($('.slick-list').width() -103);
      },0)
      }
    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer:

I removed

centerMode: true

Don't you love inheriting other peoples code